Docker Desktop: "Image couldn't be analyzed" for all images a while after installing?
I'm using Docker Desktop 4.21.2 on Windows 11 (also saw this on Windows 10). I noticed that after about a week of use it stops being able to analyze any images for the packages they contain, despite being able to after a fresh install.
So far the only temporary solution I have is to uninstall + reinstall Docker Desktop. I tried deleting all my images and containers, restarting, unselecting 'Enable Background SBOM Indexing' and none of them have fixed anything. Has anyone else come across this issue before? And why does it happen in the first place?
